# What is the exact function/meaning of "auch" here?

Tags: meaning

> Und ginge es nur ums Aussehen, wäre das ja **auch** nicht weiter schlimm. Aber ...

For the sake of breaking down the meaning of the sentence, I go with a rather literal translation here:

> = "If it were just a matter of appearance, that would indeed ***really*** not so bad. But ..."

At first, I thought this *auch* means "too/as well" in relation to what has been said in a previous context, but I realised that it might be more like "wirklich/really" to talk about a ***real*** situation.

One by one:

> - *ja* = indeed {in relation to the subsequent *aber*}
> - *auch* = wirklich/really {to talk about a real situation}
> - *nicht weiter* = not further /  not really / not so

I wonder if I'm on the right track in my interpretation?

Comment: In that sentence it could mean both *wirklich* and *ebenfalls*. We need more context. When spoken, the difference lies in emphasis. When the *auch* is over-emphasized, it means *ebenfalls* in that sentence. The problem is *wirklich* is used as a replacement for *ebenfalls*, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider this "auch" to be appropriate because it links two different instances of *limited* scope.

The hypothetical criteria here comprise *only* looks (not e.g. skills), i.e. *less* than normal or less than imaginable. Likewise, the hypothetical effect would be *less* severe than possible. This makes "auch" appropriate to use.

Imagine a situation where small cause has a large effect:

> Wenn ein Politiker Übergewicht hat, ist er schon nicht mehr wählbar.

Here the two clauses link a less important cause with a drastic effect, so "schon" is more appropriate than "auch" would be.

Comment: Thanks. So do you think that the "unlikeliness" described both in the main clause and the subordinate clause is "equal", that is to say, "**auch/equally unlikely**"?

Comment: @Alone-zee Perhaps not equal but certainly of the same sign and magnitude. Compare: "Wer ein Verbrechen begeht [severe], muss auch die Konsequenzen tragen [severe]" vs. "Wer nur blinzelt [minor cause], hat schon verloren [major effect]".